# Jquery Best practices to keep 'This' with $.klass

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, class, this

I use the Jquery plugin klass and I have some problems to use it... :/

I have a class with methods but when I want to catch events (like click) and Call method from my object I found only two methods to do it:

Problem:

```
test = $.klass({
    init: function () {
        console.log('CM');
    },

    action: function () {
        $('.test').on('click', function () {
            // Call test method
        });
    },
    test: function () {
        console.log('test');
    }
})
```

Solution 1 : Put 'This' like data

```
test = $.klass({
    init: function () {
        console.log('CM');
    },

    action: function () {
        $('.test').on('click', { context: this }, function (event) {
            event.data.context.test();
        });
    },
    test: function () {
        console.log('test');
    }
})
```

Solution 2 : Get 'global' this

```
test = $.klass({
    init: function () {
        console.log('CM');
    },

    action: function () {
        var that = this;
        $('.test').on('click', function (event) {
           that.test();
        });
    },
    test: function () {
        console.log('test');
    }
})
```

I don't like the second solution because I don't like global variable but I don't know if the first one is better...

Can you help me to choose the best one or may be have you other solution for me :)

Thanks